# Erro de instalação do Chocolatey no Windows 7 - utilizando o Prompt ou PowerShell como adm de Comando

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Olá, Estou com problemas na instalação do Chocolatey no meu Win7. Eu uso o código

@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"

E o Prompt de comando me retorna o seguinte erro:

Exceção ao chamar "DownloadString" com "1" argumento(s): "A conexão subjacente
estava fechada: Erro inesperado em um envio."
Em linha:1 caractere:54

- iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString <<<< ('https://chocolat
  ey.org/install.ps1'))

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
    Não entendi muito bem o erro. Se puderem me ajudar ficarei bastante grato!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Tive esta mesma mensagem de erro, pesquisei na documentação do Chocolately e achei algumas [opções alternativas para a instalação](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/setup#more-install-options). Fiz o download e consegui fazer a instalação.

Na página do link busque por "*Install downloaded NuGet package from PowerShell*"

1. Primeiro acessei o link, baixei o arquivo "chocolatey.0.10.16-beta-20200806.nupkg";
2. Renome-ei o aquivo para "chocolatey.0.10.16-beta-20200806.zip" e extrai;
3. Abri o Powershell como administrador;
4. Acessei a pasta "C:\MINHA_PASTA\Downloads\Chocolately\chocolatey.0.10.16-beta-20200806\tools"
5. Inseri na linha de comando: "& .\chocolateyInstall.ps1"

E instalou corretamente. Esse passo a passo está na documentação mencionada.